# Bootstrap carousel for text only not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to use carousel to display some announcement topics on my website.
but, the carousel just not displayed correctly. now, the topics inside the carousel are updated every day so I'm using javascript to add the item dynamically.

this is the code that I'm using :

**HTML**

```
<script src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="announcement-container" class="alert alert-warning">
  <div class="announcement-button-left">
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#text-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="announcement-carousel">
    <div id="text-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div id="announcement" class="carousel-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="announcement-button-right">
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#text-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel-content {
  color:black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

#text-carousel {
height: 20px;
padding: 0px;
}

.announcement-container {
display: inline-flex;
}

.announcement-text {
text-align: center;
}

.announcement-button-left {
display: inline;
}

.announcement-carousel {
display: inline-flex;
flex-grow: 1;
}
.announcement-button-right {
display: inline;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
for(i = 0; i < topics.length; i++){
  if(i==0){
    $("#announcement").append("<div class='item active'><div class='carousel-content'><div class='announcement'><p class='announcement-text'>" + topics[i][0] + "</p></div></div></div>");
  }else{
    $("#announcement").append("<div class='item'><div class='carousel-content'><div class='announcement'><p class='announcement-text'>" + topics[i][0] + "</p></div></div></div>");
  }
}      
});
```

**result**

[image]

there's no error either on my console, and as I'm pretty new at bootstrap, I would appreciate any input regarding this.

Comment: Could you put your code up as a working snippet as it'll be easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the bootstrap CSS? If I run just the code you have given, with loading jquery and bootstrap js only there is no carousel CSS.

Try this snippet, obviously you will need to adapt to load files from your preferred sources.

```js
const topics = [["Topic 1"], ["Topic 2"], ["Topic 3"]];
$(document).ready(function () {
for(i = 0; i < topics.length; i++){
  if(i==0){
    $("#announcement").append("<div class='item active'><div class='carousel-content'><div class='announcement'><p class='announcement-text'>" + topics[i][0] + "</p></div></div></div>");
  }else{
    $("#announcement").append("<div class='item'><div class='carousel-content'><div class='announcement'><p class='announcement-text'>" + topics[i][0] + "</p></div></div></div>");
  }
}      
});
```

```css
.carousel-content {
  color:black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

#text-carousel {
height: 20px;
padding: 0px;
}

.announcement-container {
display: inline-flex;
}

.announcement-text {
text-align: center;
}

.announcement-button-left {
display: inline;
}

.announcement-carousel {
display: inline-flex;
flex-grow: 1;
}
.announcement-button-right {
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="announcement-container" class="alert alert-warning">
  <div class="announcement-button-left">
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#text-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="announcement-carousel">
    <div id="text-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div id="announcement" class="carousel-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="announcement-button-right">
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#text-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

It is possible for a text-only carousel to use captions instead, see for example https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/Oxqjbq